# Legitimate regex for HTML5 form field validation

Tags: regex, html, validation

Is the following regex:

1. url: `/\b(http|https|ftp):\/\/([-A-Z0-9.]+)(\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?(\?[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?/i`
2. email: `/\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@(?:[A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,6}\b/i`

I am using them in inputs like:

```
  <section id='email-txt' class='flex-column'>
    <label id='address' for='emailTxt'>Address</label>
    <input id=emailTxt
           type='email'
           value='{{webContact.homeEmail}}'
           pattern=/\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@(?:[A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,6}\b/i>

  </section>


  <section id='col2' class='flex-column'>
    <label id='type' for='webPageUrl'>Type</label>
    <input id=webPageUrl
           type='url'
           value='{{webContact.homeEmail}}'
           placeholder='http://microsoft.com'
           required
           pattern=/\b(http|https|ftp):\/\/([-A-Z0-9.]+)(\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?(\?[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?/i>
  </section>
```

in forms but the validation is always incorrect.

Thanks

Comment: Try quoting the pattern attribute; just like you would any other attribute. This isn't a dart problem.

Comment: Your regex reject `abc@xyz` that is a valid email address, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Valid_email_addresses

Comment: quoted in single or double quotes - still does not work. Checked the regex with tools and all say its correct. Cannot understand why it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

The word boundaries `\b` are not pertinent in your case. If you do input fields validation,  try those regexes with `^` and `$`:

**url:**

```
/^(http|https|ftp):\/\/([-A-Z0-9.]+)(\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?(\?[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?$/i
```

**email:**

```
/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@(?:[A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,6}$/i
```